# I am trying to create a login page for node.js, but I am encountering issues accessing the saved data from the database

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Here is the code for creating the user to the database

```
const User = require('../database/models/User')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    User.create(req.body, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.redirect('/auth/register')
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    })
}
```

Here is the code for accessing the saved user to enable logging in

```
const User = require('../database/models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    User.findOne({ email }, (error, user) => {
        if(user) {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) => {
                if(same) {
                    req.session.userId = user._id
                    return res.redirect('/')
                } else {
                    console.log('user not found')
                    res.redirect('/auth/login')
                }
            })
        } else {
            return res.redirect('/auth/login')
        }
    });
}
```

when I run the app and try to log in I always get an error in finding the user even when I create the user immediately and try logging in

Comment: Where specifically is the error being thrown - does the console log 'user not found'? If so, that's actually not a good description of what has happened. The user was found but the decryption failed.

Comment: there is no error been thrown but if the user is saved in the database is should redirect to the home page or else should remain on the same page.. it is not redirecting to the home page even after a saved user data is used to login....and it's not throwing any errors

Comment: If it is not redirecting to `/` then presumably an error has been thrown, but you aren't doing anything with it. I guess what I'm asking is which part of the `User.findOne` callback is calling `res.redirect('/auth/login')`?

Comment: the callback takes two args (same, error)... if the user is found with same details in login form then redirect to `/` else if error then res.direct('/auth/login')

Comment: There are two places where `res.redirect('/auth/login')` can be called, either when `user` is falsy, or when `same` is falsy.  In other words, when the user is not found, or when the `bcrypt.compare` fails - all I'm trying to ask is which is it? Is the user actually not found, or is the user found but the password comparison fails?

Comment: It should be for when the user is found but the password comparison is false then `res.redirect('/auth/login')` code should run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221314/discussion-between-frederick-ottache-and-lawrence-witt).

Answer (score -1):

In the Mongo Query Like this

```
let findQuery ={
email : req.body.email
};

 User.findOne(findQuery, (error, user) => {
```

a change like this you will get a solution.

Comment: This doesn't change anything - you're just assigning the email to a new variable.

Comment: tried to change to this but I got a new error saying the password was not defined. tried adding it in the let block but it still brought the same error

Comment: Console the req.body before this line. then check 
    const { email, password } = req.body;